# Два союза подряд. Запятая

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

```
Но когда я это слышу, моя рука не тянется ни к пистолету,...
```

Здесь у нас союз **но** + союз **когда** и запятой между ними по нацкорпусу не наблюдается.
Однако в аналогичной структуре союз **тем не менее** + союз **когда** запятая ставится:

```
Тем не менее, когда я это слышу, моя рука не тянется ни к пистолету, ...
```

Почему в одинаковых синтаксических структурах разная пунктуация?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Розенталь:
После союза но запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет; ср.:
*Но, если далее противнику удавалось отбить атакующих, пехота снова бросалась в атаку* (Сим.).
*Но когда он, опираясь на палку, вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… и, не ожидая, пока его обнимут, сам стал обнимать и целовать всех, кто попадал в его объятия, что-то защемило в ране* (Павл.).
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140

Там речь о начале предложения. Для "тем не менее" такого исключения нет. Это связано с логическими ударениями: из за того, что аж три слова, на них (а именно на "менее") падает логическое ударение, которое вызывает запятую.